# Resume Parsing using Solr and TIKA

Tags: parsing, solr, nlp, apache-tika

I was going through this [slide](https://www.slideshare.net/lucenerevolution/kang-laura-using-solr-to-find-the-right-person-for-the-right-job). I'm getting little difficulty in understanding the approach.

My two queries are:

1. How does `Solr` maintain schema of `semi-structured document` like
   resumes (such as Name, Skills, Education etc)
2. Can `Apache TIKA` extract the section wise information from PDFs? Since every resume would have dissimilar sections, how do I define a
   common schema of entities?

Answer (score 0):

1. You define the schema, so that you get the fields you expect and can search in the different fields based on what kind of queries you want to do. You can lump any unknown (i.e. where you're not sure about where it belongs) values into a common search field and rank that field lower.
2. You'll have to parse the response from Tika (or a different PDF / docx parser) yourself. Just using Tika by itself will not give you an automagically structured response tuned to the problem you're trying to solve. There will be a lot of manual parsing and trying to make sense of what is what from the uploaded document, and then inserting the relevant data into the relevant field.

Answer (score 0):

We did many implementations using solr and elastic search.
And got two challenges

1. defining schema and more specific getting document to given schema
2. Then expanding search terms to more accurate and useful match. Solr, Elastic can match which they get from content, but not beyond that content.

You need to use Resume Parser like [www.rchilli.com](http://www.rchilli.com/),  Sovrn, daxtra, hireability  or any others and use their output and map to your schema. Best part is you get access to taxonomies to enhance your content is solr. 
You can use any one based on your budget and needs. But for us RChilli worked best.

Let me know if you need any further help.